# Why did Alma Dray ask about Lionel Shrike?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

In Now You See Me Alma Dray is reading about the most famous magicians in history. She mentions Lionel Shrike's tree in the card trick to Dylan Rhodes.

We later discover that

> Lionel Shrike is Dylan Rhodes' father

Is it just a massive coincidence Alma told Dylan about this particular magician or does she know the connection?

Comment: There isn't any way she could know. But even more than that, the movie didn't give the slightest hint that she knew and was playing along all the time. It was just movie coincidence that she read and told about exactly this guy (or she mentioned him because of his connection to *Thaddeus Bradley*).

Comment: Remember she also mentioned that Lionel Shrike's body was never found. Interesting...almost as interesting as the sequel in the works...remember...nothing is ever locked.

Comment: Obviously because when she was reading about Shrike she read about his connection to Thaddeous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie had plenty of plot holes.  Apparently, she was just mentioning it because Shrike was supposed to be Houdini-like.  Since the entire movie was fiction, Houdini probably didn't exist in their world.

See [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2bqfDrtd6M) for a whole host of other plot inconsistencies (and a good laugh).

Answer (score 1):

No, the reason why she is reading about him is because Dylan Rhodes first asks Thaddeus Bradley about Lionel Shrike. Thaddeus says that he revealed all Lionel's tricks in his (Thaddeus's) first show. So Lionel tried a new trick, escaping a safe from the bottom of the river.

Comment: But it is *Alma* who brings the conversdation to *Shrike*, *Dylan* (supposedly) doesn't know about him until he's mentioned in the conversation with *Thaddeus*.