# Why did Alma Dray mention Shrike's tree?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

Related to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17922/why-did-alma-dray-ask-about-lionel-shrike) about *Now You See Me*, when Alma and Dylan are waiting for the New Orleans show to begin, Alma says "Oh! By the way, I know how he did that trick". She then explains the Shrike tree trick where he planted a signed card inside a tree and waited for 18 years.

Is there a missing scene that explains the context for this? Perhaps a difference between the theatrical and extended cuts? Watching the extended cut, this is the first time that trick was mentioned. Shrike was mentioned briefly before, but only in the context of the underwater safe trick that killed him.

This line seems to come out of nowhere; why would she say "I know how he did that trick" if they hadn't previously been talking about that trick? The linked question says "She mentions Lionel Shrike's tree in the card trick to Dylan Rhodes", but I don't see any mention of that while she's doing the card trick for Dylan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reference to the trick earlier in the movie.

When they arrive in New Orleans they set up in the apartment and Alma tells Dylan about the trick (showing him the book where it is described)

> Lionel Shrike.
>
> In Central Park, he has a guy pick a card and sign it. Then he goes to a tree that has been there 20 years. They saw the tree in half. Inside the tree, encased in glass, is the card with the signature.

[image]

As far as I am aware, this scene appears in all versions of the movie. Theatrical and Extended.

For a list of the differences, see [**here.**](https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=450000)

Comment: Some how I accidentally skipped that scene (or at least my memory of it). I was re-watching the airplane scene where she does the card trick for him to try and find that conversation.